# why cannot we initialize a node without using a pointer?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have recently started learning data structure and as a beginner, I have a query while implementing linked list nodes, why do we have to initialize node using a pointer only?

```
class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node* next;
    node(int val){
        data = val;
        next = NULL;
    }
 };
 int main(){
    node* head = NULL;
    node head = NULL; // this throws an error which i cannot understand
 }
```

Comment: The constructor for `node` takes an `int` not a pointer.

Comment: Assigning NULL to a pointer means you are explicitly telling the compiler that the pointer is pointing to nowhere (rather than pointing to some random location which can cause undefined behavior in some cases). Non-pointer variables on stack doesn't need NULL assignment.

Comment: What is the text of the error?

Comment: What do you think `node head = NULL;` means exactly? A `node` contains an `int` and a `pointer` -- what would it mean for its value to be `NULL`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz what I thought was maybe we are just declaring a node we do not want it to store any value. I know I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: @user207421 'passing NULL to non pointer argument'.

Comment: as you have declared the class Node, the way to initialize the Node is to pass an integer to it - That gives you an instance of Node.  A pointer to a Node is not an instance of a Node, it only points to one.

Comment: @AndersK a node object cannot store NULL but a pointer can point to one am i correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually you can initialize the node by value. If you want to initialize a node with value, according to your constructor `node(int val)`, you have to code like below:

```
class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node* next;
    explicit node(int val){
        data = val;
        next = NULL;
    }
 };
 int main(){
    int value = 777;
    //node* head = NULL; // Initialize head pointers to null
    node head(value);   // By your constructor definition
 }
```

EDIT: By the way, marking a constructor as explicit is a very good habit to have, as it prevents unexpected conversion, as Duthomhas commented.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, I tried your suggested method and it works, I was assigning null to the node may be that was the error.

Comment: This is not correct. The constructor provided is not `explicit` so the compiler will happily perform a conversion from `int` to `node`. `node head = value;` will compile without errors or warnings.

Comment: @Kyle Oh, I checked your comment and confirmed that the compiler does not complained. I will correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: You just need to mark the constructor as `explicit`.

Comment: @Dúthomhas okay got it, thank you so much I have one more query, why do we use a pointer to create an object of a class while using the new keyword?

Comment: @Harshit Review your course notes. You use pointers when obtaining and manipulating dynamic memory.